# How to run a Rpi3 or Rpi0W as access point with a login screen?

Tags: wifi, access-point

When connecting to an open access point in a public location, the browser shows a notification to open up a 'login' page for this open network, where you can read and accept the terms and conditions, and maybe see some other information as well.

I want to create such a system using a Raspberry Pi. There are many tutorials out there that indicate how to set up the Rpi's wlan0 interface as an Access Point ('mode 2'). However, how can I send people to a small webapp hosted on the device if they connect to this AP?

Comment: I don't know how to do this, but the thing you're referring to is a "captive portal", if you want to do some Googling.